# Improving the query speed on orphan record search

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have three large tables (plus 1 million rows)

- Big1 has a Bigger1ID
- Big2 has a Bigger1ID
- Big3 has a Bigger1ID

That hold an ID to another table (plus 10 million rows)

- Bigger1 has a Biggest1ID

Which holds an ID to a final very large table (50 million rows)

- Biggest1

The issue we have found is we are carrying orphans in the Biggest1 table that hold a record in the Bigger1 table but not in the Big tables. 
I created the following query but the performance is not great, this might just be due to the size but I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this. 
I considered using LEFT JOINS to insert into a temp table, but I did not see any gain.

```
SELECT 
  Biggest.ID,
  Bigger.ID
FROM 
    Biggest JOIN Bigger ON Biggest.BiggerID = Bigger.ID
WHERE 
    Biggest.MyType IN ('type1', ' type2', 'type3')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Big1 WHERE Bigger1.BiggerID = Big1.Bigger1ID)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Big2 WHERE Bigger1.BiggerID = Big2.Bigger1ID)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Big3 WHERE Bigger1.BiggerID = Big3.Bigger1ID)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: questions seeking performance help,should  include details like execution plan,schema of tables involved and repro to test :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914288/how-to-generate-a-script-of-the-necessary-database-metadata-to-create-a-statistics-only-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

If the records are in the Bigger Table (You are doing an inner join so you seem certain of that) then you don't need to query the biggest table at all.
Then is just :

```
    SELECT * from bigger b
    Left Join Big1 b1 on b1. Bigger1ID = b. Bigger1ID
Left Join Big2 b2 on b2. Bigger1ID = b. Bigger1ID
Left Join Big3 b3 on b3. Bigger1ID = b. Bigger1ID
Where b3. Bigger1ID is null and b3. Bigger1ID is null and b3.Bigger1ID is null
```

Should be quick enough.
If you need to - Collect all the Bigger1IDs and then join to the Biggest table to filter out the Type.

EG:
 Biggest.MyType IN ('type1', ' type2', 'type3')

Comment: I need the biggest because my intentions are to remove orphans that exist in both bigger and biggest, I need the id from both.  the big tables are the parents the bigger and biggest are the children.  normally 1 record in the bigger and 5 in the biggest.  Good point i will try this.

Comment: Are you sure that you need `b3.Bigger1ID is null` three times in the `where` clause? Not `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`?